# How to compare the Json responedata and sql data in java

Tags: java, sql, json

I written the code for Post data in webservice and it sends response data and code. Same data I am posting  in the sql using select query. My scenario is I need to check responsedata and sql data are same or not.

Mysql.java

```
public ArrayList<DisputeSummaryarraylistobject> connectSqlconnectiondisputesummary() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

      ArrayList<DisputeSummaryarraylistobject> DisputeSummaryarraylistobjectlist = new ArrayList<DisputeSummaryarraylistobject>();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
         "databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=UserName;password=*****";  
      try {        
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         sqlConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
         String sqlStatement = "Enter the sql statement";
         stateMent = sqlConnection.createStatement();
         resultSet = stateMent.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
         DisputeSummaryarraylistobject disputeSummaryarraylistobject = new DisputeSummaryarraylistobject();
         while (resultSet.next())
         {
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setchargeback(resultSet.getInt("chargeback"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setactiveDisputes(resultSet.getInt("activeDisputes"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setrecentUpdates(resultSet.getInt("recentUpdates"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setrecentlyClosed(resultSet.getInt("recentlyClosed"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setresponseRequired(resultSet.getInt("responseRequired"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.inProgress(resultSet.getInt("inProgress"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setclosedInFavor(resultSet.getInt("closedInFavor"));
            disputeSummaryarraylistobject.setclosedChargebacks(resultSet.getInt("closedChargebacks"));

            DisputeSummaryarraylistobjectlist.add(disputeSummaryarraylistobject);
         }
      }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return DisputeSummaryarraylistobjectlist;
    }
```

}

Myjsonresponse.java

```
public void convertResponseoutputtojsonobject() throws IOException, ParseException {

    logger.info("convertResponseoutputtojsonobject() : BEGINs "); 
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object object = jsonParser.parse(response.toString());
    JSONArray jsArray = (JSONArray) object;
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsArray.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = iterator.next();
        list.add(jsonObj);          
    }
    logger.info(list.toString());
    logger.info("convertResponseoutputtojsonobject() : ENDS "); 
}
```

output : response data will be stored in the list.tostring() with formart

```
{
    "chargeback": 5,
    "activeDisputes": 12,
    "recentUpdates": 10,
    "recentlyClosed": 12,
    "responseRequired": 8,
    "inProgress": 4,
    "closedInFavor": 4,
    "closedChargebacks": 8
  }
```

I need compare the `list.tostring` values and sql values. Anyone can give a solution how to compare?

Comment: I think making comparison with your hands is to error prone and unreadable. I'll recommend you to use GSON to convert JSON to java Object and some ORM or JPA directly to convert DBRow to Object and then implement proper equals() to compare them...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to compare the string produced by this code with a string produced differently?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to come up with an SQL query that would produce the same string (JSON)?

Comment: Hi Marurice, select * from testtable where startdate ="02-02-2013"; this is my sql query. If i executed this query i get values like json.

Comment: Hi Vach can u give a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DisputeSummaryarraylistobject` with proper equals and hashcode method then you can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse the json data directly to the object and do a comparision. Eg.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class JsonCompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonData = "{ \"chargeback\": 5, \"activeDisputes\": 12, \"recentUpdates\": 10, \"recentlyClosed\": 12, \"responseRequired\": 8, \"inProgress\": 4, \"closedInFavor\": 4, \"closedChargebacks\": 8 }";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        DisputeSummaryarraylistobject webserviceObject = gson.fromJson(jsonData, DisputeSummaryarraylistobject.class);

        //DDObject
        DisputeSummaryarraylistobject dbObject = new DisputeSummaryarraylistobject();
        dbObject.setChargeback(5);
        dbObject.setActiveDisputes(12);
        dbObject.setRecentUpdates(10);
        dbObject.setRecentlyClosed(12);
        dbObject.setResponseRequired(8);
        dbObject.setInProgress(4);
        dbObject.setClosedInFavor(4);
        dbObject.setClosedChargebacks(8);

        System.out.println(webserviceObject.equals(dbObject));

        // If you have an array of objects
        String jsonDataArray = "[ { \"chargeback\": 5, \"activeDisputes\": 12, \"recentUpdates\": 10, \"recentlyClosed\": 12, \"responseRequired\": 8, \"inProgress\": 4, \"closedInFavor\": 4, \"closedChargebacks\": 8 }, "
                + " { \"chargeback\": 6, \"activeDisputes\": 7, \"recentUpdates\": 8, \"recentlyClosed\": 2, \"responseRequired\": 5, \"inProgress\": 14, \"closedInFavor\": 14, \"closedChargebacks\": 5 } ]";
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<DisputeSummaryarraylistobject>>() {}.getType();
        List<DisputeSummaryarraylistobject> disputeSummaryArraylistobjectList  = gson.fromJson(jsonDataArray, listType);
        System.out.println(disputeSummaryArraylistobjectList);

        //Now you can iterate through the array and compare the objects with equals.
    }

}
```

**A sample Dispute Summary Object**

```
public class DisputeSummaryarraylistobject {
    private int chargeback;
    private int activeDisputes;
    private int recentUpdates;
    private int recentlyClosed;
    private int responseRequired;
    private int inProgress;
    private int closedInFavor;
    private int closedChargebacks;

    public int getChargeback() {
        return chargeback;
    }
    public void setChargeback(int chargeback) {
        this.chargeback = chargeback;
    }
    public int getActiveDisputes() {
        return activeDisputes;
    }
    public void setActiveDisputes(int activeDisputes) {
        this.activeDisputes = activeDisputes;
    }
    public int getRecentUpdates() {
        return recentUpdates;
    }
    public void setRecentUpdates(int recentUpdates) {
        this.recentUpdates = recentUpdates;
    }
    public int getRecentlyClosed() {
        return recentlyClosed;
    }
    public void setRecentlyClosed(int recentlyClosed) {
        this.recentlyClosed = recentlyClosed;
    }
    public int getResponseRequired() {
        return responseRequired;
    }
    public void setResponseRequired(int responseRequired) {
        this.responseRequired = responseRequired;
    }
    public int getInProgress() {
        return inProgress;
    }
    public void setInProgress(int inProgress) {
        this.inProgress = inProgress;
    }
    public int getClosedInFavor() {
        return closedInFavor;
    }
    public void setClosedInFavor(int closedInFavor) {
        this.closedInFavor = closedInFavor;
    }
    public int getClosedChargebacks() {
        return closedChargebacks;
    }
    public void setClosedChargebacks(int closedChargebacks) {
        this.closedChargebacks = closedChargebacks;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + activeDisputes;
        result = prime * result + chargeback;
        result = prime * result + closedChargebacks;
        result = prime * result + closedInFavor;
        result = prime * result + inProgress;
        result = prime * result + recentUpdates;
        result = prime * result + recentlyClosed;
        result = prime * result + responseRequired;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DisputeSummaryarraylistobject other = (DisputeSummaryarraylistobject) obj;
        if (activeDisputes != other.activeDisputes)
            return false;
        if (chargeback != other.chargeback)
            return false;
        if (closedChargebacks != other.closedChargebacks)
            return false;
        if (closedInFavor != other.closedInFavor)
            return false;
        if (inProgress != other.inProgress)
            return false;
        if (recentUpdates != other.recentUpdates)
            return false;
        if (recentlyClosed != other.recentlyClosed)
            return false;
        if (responseRequired != other.responseRequired)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DisputeSummaryarraylistobject [chargeback=" + chargeback
                + ", activeDisputes=" + activeDisputes + ", recentUpdates="
                + recentUpdates + ", recentlyClosed=" + recentlyClosed
                + ", responseRequired=" + responseRequired + ", inProgress="
                + inProgress + ", closedInFavor=" + closedInFavor
                + ", closedChargebacks=" + closedChargebacks + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Syam, thanks for your updates. Its worked fine and thanks u all

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the JSON documents are the same in your client, you could also do that directly in SQL:

```sql
select cast(? as jsonb) = (select jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(...)) from ...)
```

It may not be the right approach for you, but just a thought that is often overlooked.